# I need to show on console the result with two arrays using pop and shift methods

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given arrays are array1 and array2

Array1: `['A']`
Array2: `['B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']`
Result: `['A','I','B','H','C','G','D','F','E']`

How do i achieve something like this with `.pop()` and `.shift()`.

I have tried

```
console.log(`array1: ${array1}`);
console.log(`array2: ${array2}`);
var removedItem = array2.pop();
var addedItem = array2.unshift(removedItem);
var array3 = array1.concat(array2);
console.log(`Lopputulos: ${array3}`);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the current use case, but I think you have not described your question clearly, try to write it again with some edge case.
A current example is very trivial and so probably I still think the below solution will need a little tweaking.

But based on the current problem statement, I am writing this answer.

```js
let a1 = ['A'];
let a2 = ['B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'];
let sol = [...a1];
while(a2.length){
sol.push(a2.pop());
sol.push(a2.shift());
}
console.log(sol)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro. It was my introduction course to Javascript. I think the question also seems stupid to the knowledgeable person. Though helped me and learned from you. Thanks again.